# Async File reading like socket BeginReciefeFrom(...)

Tags: c#, file, sockets, asynchronous, streamreader

I'm looking for a function, which allows me to read a file, like listening on a Port. As soon as it find's a Line, it calls a method (with callback). And that in a separate Process.
I'm using:

```
BeginRecieveFrom(socket.bytes, 0, BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref endpoint, new AsyncCallback(RecieveFromCallback), state);
```

I've been searching for a while, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you want te read the file as binary or text?

Answer (score 0):

The `Stream` class supports `BeginRead()`

Here is an example: *(read binary)*

```
// This class will keep reading until all requested byte are read.
public static class FileReader
{
    public static void ReadBytes(Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, Action complete)
    {
        stream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, (asyncResult) =>
        {
            var bytesRead = stream.EndRead(asyncResult);

            offset += bytesRead;
            count -= bytesRead;

            if (count == 0)
                complete();
            else
                ReadBytes(stream, buffer, offset, count, complete);

        }, null);
    }
}
```

---

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
var bytesNeeded = buffer.Length;

var fileStream = new FileStream("filename.ext", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

if (bytesNeeded > fileStream.Length)
    bytesNeeded = (int)fileStream.Length;

FileReader.ReadBytes(fileStream, buffer, 0, bytesNeeded, () =>
{
    Trace.WriteLine("done");
});
```

This will read until [count] bytes are readed. This is ofcourse an **example**..

Comment: It's better to use the Task-based asynchronous methods like [Stream.ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readasync(v=vs.110).aspx). The code becomes a *lot* simpler

Comment: Agree, but I was just answering the question: _"Async File reading like socket BeginReciefeFrom(…)"_

Comment: That does look like something I'm looking for, thanks for the help. I'm trying it out right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course read a file asynchronously since it is an IO operation.

I think what you are looking for is something similar to the following, but please note that, this example uses the new async/await asynchronous pattern.

```
public class Program
{
    public delegate void NewLineCallback(string lineContent);

    public static void NewLineReceived(string lineContent)
    {
        if (lineContent != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New line has been read from the file. Number of chars: {0}. Timestamp: {1}", lineContent.Length, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.fff"));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All the file content have been read. Timestamp: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.fff"));
        }
    }

    public static async void ReadFile(NewLineCallback newLineCallback)
    {
        StreamReader fileInputStreamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("c:\\temp\\mytemptextfile.txt"));

        string newLine;

        do
        {
            newLine = await fileInputStreamReader.ReadLineAsync();
            newLineCallback(newLine);
        }
        while (newLine != null);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadFile(NewLineReceived);

        Console.ReadLine(); // To wait for the IO operation to complete.
    }
}
```